# How do I send code snippets in MS Teams using Python's SDK framework?

Tags: python, bots, botframework, microsoft-teams

I can't seem to find a way to send code snippets using Python's SDK module. [This is what I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNjsQ.png).

I tried using three backsticks ```` ``` ```` and `<codeblock>` tags, but these are regular code blocks and not snippet codes.

````py
code_snippet = Activity(
    type=ActivityTypes.message,
    text=f'```python\n{out}\n```',
)
await turn_context.send_activity(code_snippet)
````

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please select the Python langugae instead of text.
Refer following screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuicy.png

Comment: This is not what I'm asking. I want to send this using Python code via the bot SDK framework.

Comment: Is this a programming question? If yes, please [edit] your question and include the relevant code as a [mcve]. If this is about using ms teams, it's off-topic here. See [help/on-topic].

Comment: Aren't tags enough to tell that a question is programming-related? Anyway, I edited my post and included one thing I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TextFormat property of a message can be used to specify the format of the text. The TextFormat property can be set to plain, markdown, or xml. The default value for TextFormat is markdown.

Example:

```
IMessageActivity message =  Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
message.Text = "Hello!";
message.TextFormat = "plain";
message.Locale = "en-Us";
```

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-create-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#customizing-a-message

There is no any text format available for code snippets.

If you wish you can suggest this feature here:
[Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)